# Convert Error 2306 to 0 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing out a Macro that smooths data to reduce jagged edges etc.

I need a way to replace cells which produce Errors, such as Error 2036 or `#Num` values in cells to `0` I would like to do this within the `For loop` as the previous values is used in calculating this value.

I have tried to `If` statements to solve this but to no avail.

The code I have tried to use is as follows.

The 3 code variations are from the definations from teh excel website naming what the error is.

```
If LineAngle = xlErrNum Then
    LineAngle = 0
End If
```

or

```
If LineAngle = "Error 2036 Then
    LineAngle = 0
End If
```

or

```
If LineAngle = "#Num" Then
    LineAngle = 0
End If
```

Which ever code I run I always get  **Run-time error 13 Type mismatch**

Any help you are able to provide is very useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use iserror:

```
If iserror(LineAngle) Then
    LineAngle = 0
End If
```

Comment: Excellent Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you have a column of data like:

[image]

Then without a loop:

```
Sub ErrorKiller()
    Columns(4).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Value = 0
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment :)